# how can i Translate this NodeJs code to c# code?

Tags: model-view-controller

```
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', notificationsKey);
hmac.update(JSON.stringify(params, Object.keys(params).sort()));
const signature = hmac.digest('hex');
```

Comment: [HMAC.Create Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmac.create?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Actually, what you probably want is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512?view=net-5.0).

Comment: hmac.update(JSON.stringify(params, Object.keys(params).sort()));
const signature = hmac.digest('hex');

I'm not sure about this part.